# Django multi languages by files

Tags: javascript, html, django, multilingual, translate

hello i have read lots of stuff about multilingual, translate  in Django, but i'm looking for something different, like this:
Have files .json or a table with something like:

```
  string     EN         FR         PT
  str-1     login     Entrer      Entrar
  str-2     Next      Suivant     Seguinte
```

...

in code, something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">{resource.str-1}</button>
```

Someone know any library or method to doing this easily and quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Rosetta could be the best choice here, I've used it for a long time and it's great.
Here the [documentation](https://django-rosetta.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the [github page](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta)